# Connecting project in Monaca Mobile restful api backend with mysql database

Tags: angularjs, api, rest, onsen-ui, monaca

Connecting project in Monaca Mobile restful api backend with mysql database

I have a backend developed with php and mysql with various restful apis consultation, inclusion, exclusion ready. I need to connect the mobile project in Monaca this backend by apis from our server.
I'm trying different codes using angular, but nothing has certain data. If I can not make this connection will give up working with monaca.

Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Could not find a working rest example. This example connects to remote server and pulls data from a remote server. Changing URL should take care of the rest.

https://github.com/argelius/onsen-weather-sample

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10764339)

Comment: James K Polk: The above link answers the questions asked and the only  thing needed to get it to work is to change the URL and handle the data and assign it to the respective dom element. The link page is a dedicated app for handling data for monaca.